# Apache mod_dav_svn, AuthzSVNAccessFile equivalent in SQL

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, mod-auth-mysql

In the process of moving away from flat configuration files, I'm seeking for the equivalent of AuthzSVNAccessFile directive, using SQL (MySQL preferred).

I am well aware of mod_auth_mysql, but it's for **user auth** only.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Started a bounty so I will not get '● Tumbleweed'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the perfect solution! [mod_authz_svn_db](http://christopher.wojno.com/articles/2007/08/19/what-is-mod_authz_svn_db).

Answer (score 0):

mod_authz_svn only have one method of authorization, and that's with AuthzSVNAccessFile.

However, if you would like the configuration itself to be stored in an SQL server, you could combine that with a script which will generate the config file. 
The config file can be generated upon change or periodically with a timed job (a cronjob perhaps)